# curl POST request

Tags: python, curl

Hello we have problem to POST data using curl !!

```
curl "http://127.0.0.1:8000/construct" -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"journal_id": "JE000001", "entry_date" : "2016-11-06", "create_time" : "2016-11-06 18:00:00", "created_by": "Adam", "post_status": "P", "account_code" : "100000", "amount" : 16453.24, "dr_cr" : "C"}'
```

Return 400

```
@app.route("/construct", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def construct():
if request.method == 'POST':
    data = request.form['data']
    data1 = loads(data)
    conn, cursor = database_connect()
    data1 = data_contruct_new(data1)
    data1['pre_hash'] = get_pre_hash(cursor)
    data1['nouce'] = call_nouce()
    data1['hash'] = call_hash(data1)
    conn.close()
    return jsonpify(data1)
else:
    return request.method # return method for test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service is expecting doubly-encoded data:

```
data = request.form['data']
data1 = loads(data)
```

Instead of just parsing the contents of the request as JSON, you're parsing the contents of the request as www-form-urlencoded, with a single field named `data`, and then parsing the contents of that form field as JSON.

The [`form`](https://flask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#flask.Request.form) field is the incoming contents parsed as a form. If you don't have one, don't use this.

---

If you want to parse the raw contents, that's either [`data`](https://flask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#flask.Request.data) or [`get_data`](https://flask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#flask.Request.get_data):

```
data = request.data
```

… or:

```
data = request.get_data()
```

---

But if you've done everything properly on both sides, you don't even need this, just [`json`](https://flask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#flask.Request.json) or [`get_json`](https://flask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#flask.Request.get_json):

```
data1 = request.get_json()
```

---

If you, for some reason, really do want doubly-encoded data, you need to generate that on the client side, and send the right Content-Type. That would look something like this mess:

'curl "http://127.0.0.1:8000/construct" -X POST -F 'data=%7B%22journal_id%22%3A%20%22JE000001%22%2C%20%22entry_date%22%20%3A%20%222016-11-06%22%2C%20%22create_time%22%20%3A%20%222016-11-06%2018%3A00%3A00%22%2C%20%22created_by%22%3A%20%22Adam%22%2C%20%22post_status%22%3A%20%22P%22%2C%20%22account_code%22%20%3A%20%22100000%22%2C%20%22amount%22%20%3A%2016453.24%2C%20%22dr_cr%22%20%3A%20%22C%22%7D'

Hopefully you can see that this is not what you actually want, unless the broken server side is completely out of your hands and can't be fixed.